# edit text in android setText variable

Tags: android

Good morning have a question and would like to see if someone can help me.

I have a number of textview defined

```
TextView Casilla1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla1); 
TextView Casilla2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla2); 
TextView Casilla3 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla3); 
TextView Casilla4 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla4);
```

etc ... up to 42 boxes.

text and would like to change their conditions through exactly depending on the month in which this activity have to change the text in the TextViews.

```
for (int i = 1; i <30, i + +) {
             String x = "Casilla" + i; 
             x.setText (i); 
         }
```

This would be something if the setText for what is inside recognize him. but it gives me error.

There would be some way to do this?.

what I want is to go textview renaming the function that is defined in the meter, adding the String as a variable plus the number of the counter which is at that time. Do not know how that recognizes the resulting String setText function and can modify the text with the counter variable.

Not if you understand me because I'm writing Through a translator.

Forgive my mistakes as I am new to the forum and android programming, I have consulted a lot in this forum but today is the first time I check.

Comment: What is diasmes? And `String.setText`????

Comment: Maybe a listview is a better solution than this strange code?

Comment: Use listview and dynamically set the text. Dont go for 42 textview

Comment: 42 TextViews? bad solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the views in array:

```
TextView[] Casilla = new TextView[42];

Casilla[0] = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla1);
Casilla[1] = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TxtVCasilla2);
// ...
```

and access them later by its index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Casilla.length, i++) {
    Casilla[i].setText(""); 
}
```

Just mentioning the alternative, since seems the use of `getIdentifier()` is discouraged and displaying these in `ListView` might not be what you want (nothing suggests it is - 42 could be a fixed number, like 64 would be for a chess board for example).

Comment: solution that also I would do. I've tried but I closed the application but does not give me any error or compile code. No might be wrong. The error on the line rises. Casilla[i].setText("");

Comment: Have you initialized each element of an array you are accessing (all 42 if you are using this loop). Are all views actually found (`findViewById()` does not return `null` for neither of them)? What is the error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

One you are using is a bad solution. But if its must, you can refer the textviews like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<diasmes; i++) {       
    int txtViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("TxtVCasilla"+ i, "id", getPackageName());
    TextView tvCasilla=(TextView)findViewById(txtViewId);    
    tvCasilla.setText(i);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Id in an array:

```
int[] Casilla  = new int[42];
Casilla[0] = R.id.TxtVCasilla1;
Casilla[1] = R.id.TxtVCasilla2;
Casilla[2] = R.id.TxtVCasilla3;
```

And set the text like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Casilla.length, i++) {
 TextView casillaTextView= (TextView) findViewById (id);
 casillaTextView.setText(i); 
 }
```

Comment: it gives me error on this line. TextView casillaTextView= (TextView) findViewById (id); the id goes and tells me in red  Error:(173, 64) error: cannot find symbol variable id

Comment: TextView casillaTextView= (TextView) findViewById (Casilla[i]);